# Difference of timestamp event rows using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two event tables with timestamped data: Registered, Signed_In.

Both have rows such as: original_timestamp, user_id

I am trying to find out users who haven't signed in within 30 days after registering. I have used the following query but I cannot add a WHERE clause to it.

I tried a query but I am getting hourly difference, whereas I wanted days difference which is unsupported in BigQuery.

```
SELECT Signed_In.user_id, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Registered.original_timestamp, Signed_In.original_timestamp, HOUR) AS days_difference
FROM `test_db.Signed_In` signed_in
JOIN `test_db.Registered` registered
ON Signed_In.user_id = Registered.user_id 
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
WHERE days_difference > '30'
```

I am getting two columns: user_id, days_difference but the days_difference shows hours and my WHERE clause is rejected when I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below code-

Note: Using Ordinal Position for GROUP BY and ORDER BY is not a good practice. Its always safe and standard to use the column names directly.

```
SELECT Signed_In.user_id, 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Registered.original_timestamp, Signed_In.original_timestamp, HOUR) AS days_difference
FROM `test_db.Signed_In` signed_in
JOIN `test_db.Registered` registered
ON Signed_In.user_id = Registered.user_id 
WHERE DATE_DIFF(Registered.original_timestamp, Signed_In.original_timestamp, Day) > '30'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Gives me:
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword WHERE at [20:1]

Comment: Can you please check with ---- WHERE DATEDIF(Registered.original_timestamp, Signed_In.original_timestamp, Day) > 30

Comment: It doesn't accept WHERE clauses at the end of the query.

Comment: Opss!! WHERE clause should be before the GROUP by. Sorry for overlooking that. Can you check the changed code now? with both date_diff option.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `HOUR` to `DAY` in your [query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions):

`SELECT Signed_In.user_id, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Registered.original_timestamp, Signed_In.original_timestamp, DAY) AS days_difference`

[Correct values are](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions):

> - `MICROSECOND`
> - `MILLISECOND`
> - `SECOND`
> - `MINUTE`
> - `HOUR`
> - `DAYOFWEEK`
> - `DAY`
> - `DAYOFYEAR`
> - `WEEK`: Returns the week number of the date in the range [0, 53]. Weeks begin with Sunday, and dates prior to the first Sunday of the year are in week 0.
> - `WEEK(<WEEKDAY>)`: Returns the week number of `timestamp_expression` in the range [0, 53]. Weeks begin on `WEEKDAY`. `datetime`s prior to the first `WEEKDAY` of the year are in week 0. Valid values for `WEEKDAY` are `SUNDAY`, `MONDAY`, `TUESDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, `THURSDAY`, `FRIDAY`, and `SATURDAY`.
> - `ISOWEEK`: Returns the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) week number of the `datetime_expression`. `ISOWEEK`s begin on Monday. Return values are in the range [1, 53]. The first `ISOWEEK` of each ISO year begins on the Monday before the first Thursday of the Gregorian calendar year.
> - `MONTH`
> - `QUARTER`
> - `YEAR`
> - `ISOYEAR`: Returns the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) week-numbering year, which is the Gregorian calendar year containing the Thursday of the week to which `date_expression` belongs.
> - `DATE`
> - `DATETIME`
> - `TIME`

Comment: What about the WHERE clause ? To find a 30-day difference ?

Comment: Also, it is giving me weird results :)
I added:
WHERE DATE(Register.original_timestamp) >= "2019-01-01" and I am getting days difference of 600 days which cannot be possible for a user to register on anytime in 2019 and open their app 2 years later xD